# Subtract certain hours from a time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I want to know the time when 12 hrs and 30 mins is subtracted from a time let us say 10:00 AM(it should display 9:30 PM). But since Excel, by default, stores this date as 1st Jan  1990, I am getting a negative timing and Excel does not display it. How do I make sure that when a time is entered in a cell,I can subtract certain hours from it and display the time in AM/PM format?

PS: I tried changing it to 1904 format,but this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula, where A1 is where your time is:

```
=MOD(A1-TIME(12,30,0),1)
```

[image]

Comment: @Guru No problem. When you're confident your problem has been solved, don't forget to mark the answer that worked for you with the tick on the left :)